# Fatal Exception SCAN BLE DEVICES

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to scan Ble Devices , but `stopLeScan` is deprecated for Android 5.0+ , for this  i use `public void onScanResult` but when i executed , log show this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ponny.org.telemed/ponny.org.telemed.Vistas.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ponny.org.telemed.Vistas.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ponny.org.telemed-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2465)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)

If i comment startLeScan , the apps run

```
private void scanearDispositivo(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandlerScan.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                controladorBLE.getAdapter().stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        controladorBLE.getAdapter().startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
     /*   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            controladorBLE.getAdapter().getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(new ScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"BLE",result.getDevice().getName());
                    }else
                    {Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"BLE","Nada");}
                }
            });
        }*/
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        controladorBLE.getAdapter().stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    }
```